# Liferay hook for calendar portlet in Liferay version 6.2

Tags: jsp, calendar, liferay, portlet, portal

Can someone point out "How to customize Calendar portlet" in Liferay version 6.2 using Hooks?

The problem is that, the Calendar jsp files are not being shown in Customizable jsp list in liferay-hook.xml configuration file.

All I want to do is add few new buttons, change the labels and add some new actions in existing Calendar portlet in Liferay portal 6.2.

Can someone let me know how this has to be done step by step?

Comment: Calender related jsps are shown in liferay-hook.xml configuration file, even if its not shown you can override them in hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar portlet can not be hooked because it is a separate plugin.
So, you must get plugin from github at url https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/6.2.x/portlets/calendar-portlet
Next, you could edit any file of this plugin.
Finally, you could build project using ant and deploy it into your liferay portal.

Answer (score 3):

maybe this guide is the right starting point. You have not to create an hook but a plugin that extends another plugin:

https://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/lp-6-1-dgen02-creating-plugins-to-extend-plugins-0

Comment: for Liferay 6.2: https://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-plugins-to-extend-plugins-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-03-en

Answer (score -1):

With Liferay Hook you can customize the jsps

https://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/customizing-jsps-by-extending-the-original

and override struts-actions

https://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/override-and-add-struts-actions-with-hook-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en

Comment: Sorry, you can't use hooks to customize plugins. BTW, the Calendar portlet is a MVCPortlet, not a Struts one...

Comment: Ups, sorry, you have right - the calendar portlet is since Liferay 6.2 separate plugin.